# Probability of winning at a specific game

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A tennis match is played as a series of POINTS, contained within GAMES, which in turn are contained within SETS.

Suppose Djokovic plays a set of tennis against Murray under these rules, and his probability of winning a point is 0.48. Assuming the probability of winning a point remains constant throughout, what would be the probability of Djokovic winning the set 7-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first determine the probability of winning a single game:

To simplify notation, let $p = 0.48$.

Next, let $P(D)$ be the probability that Djokovic wins a single game.

$D$ can occur in the following disjoint situations:

Djokovic wins four points in a row: $p^4$.

Djokovic wins wins four points while Murray gets only one: $\dbinom{4}{1}p^4(1-p)$.

Djokovic wins four points while Murray gets only two: $\dbinom{5}{2}p^4(1-p)^2$.

Plus the probability that they reach Deuce and Djokovic eventually wins (probability to be determined).

Let $E$ be the event that they reach Deuce. This happens with probability: $\dbinom{6}{3}p^3(1-p)^3$

The probability that Djokovic will win from Deuce is:

$$P(D|E) = p^2+2p(1-p)P(D|E)$$

Solving for $P(D|E)$ gives $\dfrac{p^2}{1-2p+2p^2}$.

So, the probability of $P(D\cap E) = P(D|E)P(E) = \dbinom{6}{3}\dfrac{p^5(1-p)^3}{1-2p+2p^2}$

Thus:

$$P(D) = p^4\left( 1 + \dbinom{4}{1}(1-p) + \dbinom{5}{2}(1-p)^2 + \dbinom{6}{3}\dfrac{p(1-p)^3}{1-2p+2p^2} \right) = \dfrac{1375854336}{3056640625}$$

The only way for Djokovic to win 7-5 is if they tie at 5 games each, then Djokovic wins two in a row. If $q = \dfrac{1375854336}{3056640625}$, then the probability of this happening is:

$$\dbinom{10}{5}q^7(1-q)^5 \approx 0.047428310143589076989815246904379009553045283963625581247$$

Comment: I updated the calculations. I rounded too much, apparently. Using Wolframalpha, I got better results by treating $0.48 = \dfrac{12}{25}$, forcing Wolframalpha to calculate exactly rather than letting it round. Then, you can do all rounding at the end.

Comment: is there anyway to have a generic way of approaching this type f problem? what if p=054 and Djokovic needs to win by 6-4 for example?

Comment: Yes, the general formula for $P(D)$ is true for any $p$. Plug in $p=0.54 = \dfrac{27}{50}$. This gives the probability of Djokovic winning a single game. Then for winning 6-4, Set $q = P(D)_{p=\tfrac{27}{50}} = \dfrac{3679697484}{6142578125}$, and the probability you are looking for is $\dbinom{9}{4}q^6(1-q)^4 \approx 0.15049$

Comment: In general, if Djokovic wins 6 games and Murray wins $k$, the probability of this occurence is $\dbinom{6+k-1}{k}q^6(1-q)^k$. The problem above shows 7-5, and 7-6 implies they tie at 5, then tie at 6, and finally Djokovic wins the last game: $$\dbinom{10}{5}\dbinom{2}{1}q^7(1-q)^6$$. Again, $q = P(D)$ calculated for whatever value you assign to $p$.

Comment: What the first calculation is doing is, consider a sequence of letters DMDMDDMDD where once you have six D's, you stop (and Djokovic won). The probability of that sequence is $p$ for each $D$ and $1-p$ for each $M$. So, if there are 6 $D$'s and $k$ $M$'s, then the probability of that exact sequence of games is $p^6(1-p)^k$. But, how many sequences are there? Well, if Murray wins $k$ games, they can be interspersed with any of Djokovic's first five wins. So, of the first $5+k$ games, choose $k$ of them that Murray won. The rest go to Djokovic. The sixth game goes to Djokovic and he wins the set

Comment: The probability that Djokovic will win over Murray (any score) is $$\sum_{k=0}^4 \dbinom{5+k}{k}q^6(1-q)^k + \dbinom{10}{5}q^7(1-q)^5 + \dbinom{10}{5}\dbinom{2}{1}q^7(1-q)^6 \\ = 210 q^6 + 36 q^7 - 3339 q^8 + 9520 q^9 - 12474 q^{10} + 8820 q^{11} - 3276 q^{12} + 504 q^{13}$$

Comment: Mainly, I just go on these forums while I am stuck on a software problem. Solving other problems is a welcome distraction.

Comment: just one more thing... I don't understand this part at all:
The probability that Djokovic will win from Deuce is:

$$P(D|E) = p^2+2p(1-p)P(D|E)$$

Solving for $P(D|E)$ gives $\dfrac{p^2}{1-2p+2p^2}$.

Comment: why do you have P(D|E) on the right hand side of the equation as well?

Comment: The notation $p^2$ is the probability of Djokovic winning two points in a row. $p(1-p)+(1-p)p = 2p(1-p)$ is the probability of Djokovic winning, then Murray winning (or vise versa) going back to Deuce. So, the probability of Djokovic winning from Deuce is the probability of Djokovic winning in two points, plus the probability of playing two points, returning to Deuce, then Djokovic winning from Deuce.

Comment: Here's another example. Suppose you have a fair coin. You will keep flipping it. What is the probability that it eventually flips heads? $P(H) = \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}P(H)$ means that there is a 50% chance of flipping heads on one flip, otherwise, there is a 50% chance of flipping tails, and you are back to where you started. You can solve for $P(H)$ and you get $1$. In other words, if you keep flipping a coin an infinite number of times, with probability 1, you will eventually flip heads.

Comment: This method of solving for a probability when you can return to the base state is always possible for sequences of Bernoulli trials (like winning a game by at least two points).